# Elements in bootstrap filterbar not correctly sized

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a filter on top of my grid. I defined a custom filter class. In this filterclass I also try to incorperate a checkbox that is in the same style as my inputbox. For some reason I cannot get it the same size as the rest of my elements. Below the fiddle of what I'm doing. Can someone point me out what I'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6763/

```
<div class="FilterBar">
    <div>
        <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
            <span class="input-group-addon ">Set date</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon ">Group Flocks</span>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">Filter</button>
    </div>
```

```
 .FilterBar {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}
.FilterBar > div {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.Toolbar .btn-group, .Toolbar .btn-group-vertical {
    vertical-align: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.form-control has line-height: 1.42857;

.input-group-addon has line-height: 1;

See http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6766/ I added

```
.input-group-addon {
    line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

U can add class "form-control" to Group Flocks and add one more class .some with line-height: 20px;
HTML

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon form-control some">Group Flocks</span>
    <span class="input-group-addon"> <input type="checkbox"/> </span>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.some {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6764/ this is not the best solution

u can try to put all your line in div with class="row" and give all tabs some sizes like .col-xs-4